# How to add google map to ios6 sdk

Tags: iphone, ios6, google-maps-sdk-ios

When i try to add Google map to ios6  according to this Link [Google MAP](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start#getting_the_google_maps_sdk_for_ios)

and i get the API KEY and put it in my app but it crashed and the reason "Google MAP SDK for ios must be Initialized via [GMSServices ProvideAPIKey:...]"

Can any body help me, give me video how to do it any thing ...

```
    #import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"AIzaSyBoOGGGQnvDydbKcxGeB1of6wu2ibE6Rjk"];

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you do [step 8 here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start#adding_the_google_maps_sdk_for_ios_to_your_project)?

If you did, can you update your question with the code for your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method?

**UPDATE:**

Move the call to `[GMSServices provideAPIKey:]` higher up in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method, somewhere before this line:

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
```

This line sets the root view controller, which will cause the view controller's root view to be allocated, by calling `loadView`. In Google's sample code `loadView` is what creates the `GMSMapView`, and so with the code as you have it now, you are trying to create a `GMSMapView` before providing the API key, which causes the Google Maps SDK for iOS to crash.

Also by the way, you had placed your call to `[GMSServices provideAPIKey:]` after the return statement, so it would never get called.

Comment: Hi @TaherZaki, I've added an update which should fix the problem.

Comment: can u please check through this and give me some information  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20322927/error-using-google-maps-in-ios/20324862?noredirect=1#20324862

Answer (score 0):

Move your GMSServices provideAPIKey to the top of the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions,
that will fix your issue as right now you're returning before providing the API Key.

Answer (score 0):

If you moved it and still get an error, here is what I did :

Copy the file **GoogleMaps.bundle** file into your framework folder in Xcode

*"GoogleMaps.framework/Versions/A/Resources/GoogleMaps.bundle"*

..and make sure it's in your Targets (not Project) Build Phases settings under "Copy Bundle Resources"

Answer (score 0):

Start your delegate like this instead of yours :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"AIzaSyB2LJ2ppIVtkNh0lkG9J1tXW2RcHtI0FKY"];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    //////

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I moved this line :

```
[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"myAPIKey"];
```

in the method **viewDidLoad** and now it works.