# Error using Google Maps in IOS?

Tags: ios, google-maps, linker-errors

I am creating a mapView in iOs, using Google Maps Api.
I did it by referring this link

[Document](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start)
And I am getting few errors like

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_objc_setProperty_nonatomic", referenced from:
  -[GMSx_PBGeneratedMessage setExtensionRegistry:] in GoogleMaps(ProtocolBuffers.o)
```

[image]
I am fed up with this, can anybody kindly help with this.
[image]

Comment: what is ur Deployment target?

Comment: i am asking deployment target. I think ur deployment target is 5.0 check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19222427/google-map-on-iphone-exception

Comment: Is this line correct ,                         mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 360, 480) camera:camera];

Comment: GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86 longitude:151.20 zoom:6];

Comment: i never used googel-maps. so i dnt knw about this..

Comment: k, no prob, Is there anybody else to help

Comment: The error is that, map is not displayed in the simulator

Comment: I got it. I am using xcode4.3.3. It seems to use google maps, should have atleast 4.5 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Kalpesh was on the right track with his comment. Your screenshot shows you as running with the iOS 5.1 simulator, but the current version of the maps iOS SDK requires iOS 6.0 or newer.

My answer which Kalpesh linked to explains this in more detail:

[google map on iphone exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19222427/google-map-on-iphone-exception)

I noticed you commented on that other answer though, so which version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: I am using Google Maps SDK version 1.4.3

Comment: actually, I have cleared the error by using lower version, now thw problem, I am getting an output as above, map is not getting displayed

Comment: Right - you should probably raise this as a separate question, rather than mixing it up with the SDK version issue of your original question. When you raise the new question, post the code you're using, and also any messages which get logged to the console.

Comment: I have given the link above, refered by the word "document"

Comment: I got it. I am using xcode4.3.3. It seems to use google maps, should have atleast 4.5 version

Answer (score 0):

The errors you see are linker errors telling you that the symbols are not available for the simulator architecture (i386).

You are not linking a simulator-compatible version of the library (or perhaps you missed the step of adding the library to your project to be linked).

I don't know the Google Maps SDK, but it is possible that it doesn't have a simulator-compatible binary within the library file.